# Is it possible have something like the GROUP BY clause in an Android managedQuery?

Tags: android, group-by, contactscontract

I'm planning to support Android devices from 2.0 onwards so I am using a managedQuery to query contacts.  I get multiple results for people with the same name and phone number so I would like those results to be grouped.  (That is I want each name and phone number combination to be unique)

IS it possicle to group these results in a managed query (similar to the GROUP BY clause in SQL)

Mel

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hack in the `selection` statement like `"1) GROUP BY (" + Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;`.